# Has RetainInstance become the correct way to handle configuration changes in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was browsing through the new camera API and came across this file:

https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/GalleryFragment.kt

it seems that the way to avoid problems with configuration changes is to use `retainInstance = true`

is this the suggested best practice nowadays? are we moving away from viewmodel? or is this just a convenience because they wished to just showcase the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this the suggested best practice nowadays?

No.

> are we moving away from viewmodel?

No. At least, not now, and not to retained fragments. We are moving *away* from retained fragments *to* viewmodels.

> or is this just a convenience because they wished to just showcase the API?

My guess is that it is copied from some older sample of theirs. That particular fragment has nothing to do with CameraX.